# CGMiner settings so that Photoshop usage isn't slow

Tags: miner-configuration, cgminer, performance

Currently I have two settings for CGMiner, using a Radeon 6850 for home usage.

One for casual work, and one for night-time (light and heavy).

However, even at the casual settings Photoshop is very slow to use, so I have to switch it off completely.

Are there are any settings that will give priority to Photoshop (and other applications), when CGMiner is running? That way I can leave it running all day, but the hash rate simply drops when other programs require the GPU.

Comment: Maybe you can add what settings your currently using? General rule of thumb is to lower the intensity and your system will overall perform better while mining.

Comment: My "easy" settings are: `setx GPU_MAX_ALLOC_PERCENT 100
setx GPU_USE_SYNC_OBJECTS 1
.\cgminer-3.7.2-windows\cgminer.exe --scrypt -o stratum+tcp://dogeu.nut2pools.com:5585 -u xxx.yyy -p zzz -w 128 -g 2 --auto-fan --thread-concurrency 3840 --intensity 9 --shaders 960`

Comment: If I set GPU_MAX_ALLOC_PERCENT to say 50 or so, would this only utilise half of the GPU?  What I'm ideally looking for is some kind of dynamic allocation, rather than a fixed setting upon startup.

Comment: my 6970 struggles massively when altering from its stock settings. Try removing the thread concurrency and shaders along with putting intensity down to 7. Having said this my performance on scrypt with cgminer has always been poor even when pushed hard.